# Difference between concept and idea?

Tags: meaning

whenever I search for both meanings I get confused:

a concept is "an abstract idea." from Oxford Dictionary

an idea is "an opinion or belief" according to Oxford Dictionary

Comment: Doesn't the difference exist in your language?

Comment: A **concept** is a kind of **idea**. [This page](https://simplicable.com/new/concept) says: *Any idea that doesn't correspond to a specific physical thing is a concept.* That may be a generalisation, but it might show you the difference.

Answer (score 1):

In some contexts the words mean the same with different nuance.  "Concept" is bigger and more important.  A concept is a combination of many ideas:

> What is your concept for the design of our next-generation sports car?
>
> I want it sleek and low, modern, but with classic finishing.

The concept is very general and rather abstract.

Ideas are more small-scale and more concrete:

> I have an idea; let's make the steering wheel out of wood.

An idea is the result of mental activity,  but it is something definite specific and focussed.  "Idea" is also a much more common word than "concept", so if you are not sure, use "idea".

Comment: People will say: **A thought / idea has just occurred to me**. This sense of something popping into one's head is NOT described as a concept. The motor industry talks about **concept cars**, one-off models that are intended to attract publicity and test public reaction.